# Simple SQL Server Email Function?

Tags: sql-server

I need a quick and easy way to do a query and create an HTML-based email (no attachments) for SQL Server Management Studio.

The simple query:

```
select Customer from [ArCustomer+] where KeyAccount = 'Y'
```

which will generate a list of customers that have KeyAccount set to Y.

I believe I'm supposed to create a cursor but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I'm all over the place here, but I think I've got most of the mailer set up. Can someone help me correct this?

```
DECLARE 
        @lCustomer          varchar(10) 
        ;

SELECT A.Customer
FROM [ArCustomer+] A 
    Where 1=1
    AND KeyAccount = 'Y'
    --AND TCReviewDate > getdate() + 365
    --AND B.UserField1 = @lCsrInit 

-- ----------
-- If we have something to report - go for it
-- ----------
IF @lCsrCnt > 0
    Begin
        PRINT 'Running Report for ' + convert(varchar(5), @lCsrCnt) + ' - ' + @lCsrInit


                DECLARE rpt_cursor CURSOR FOR 
                    SELECT
                A.Customer
                FROM [ArCustomer+] A 

                Where 1=1
                AND KeyAccount = 'Y'
                --AND TCReviewDate > getdate() + 365
                --AND B.UserField1 = @lCsrInit 

                OPEN rpt_cursor

                FETCH NEXT FROM rpt_cursor 
                INTO    
                        @lCustomer      
                        ;
                                            
                set @lBody = '<BR><BR> The following customers are Key Accounts:' 
                
                
                    set @lBody = @lBody + '<BR>' + Customer
                           
                    FETCH NEXT FROM rpt_cursor 
                    INTO   
                        @lCustomer      ;
                END

                CLOSE rpt_cursor;
                DEALLOCATE rpt_cursor;
                
                set @lSubject = 'Key Accounts List '

                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'Default Mail' ,
                --@recipients = @lCsrEmail,
                @recipients = 'test@test.com,
                @body = @lBody,
                @subject = @lSubject,
                @attach_query_result_as_file = 0,
                @body_format= 'HTML';
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to post code with someone's actual email address in it on a public forum?

Comment: @ErikDarling This was my email address. Thank you for pointing this out however. It has been changed.

Comment: Besides sample data as Peter recommended, please always tag what version of SQL Server you're using too. For example, if you were on 2016 or newer, the `STRING_AGG()` function can be used to simplify Peter's solution even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time you should add some scripts to generate some data to play with.
You don't need a cursor for this. I guess you would like to have something like this.

This will email the list of customers (you need to edit the msdb part) in a nice html format.

```
-- ----------
-- If we have something to report - go for it
-- ----------
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM   [ARCustomer+]
             WHERE  KeyAccount = 'Y'
          )
BEGIN

   SET @Body = N'<br/><br/>The following customers are Key Accounts:<br/><br/>
    <table border = 1> 
    <tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    </tr>
    ' + CAST((
               SELECT
                     ac.Customer AS td,
                     ''
               FROM  dbo.[ARCustomer+] AS ac
               WHERE ac.KeyAccount = 'Y'
               FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'</table>';



END;

-- do mail with body..
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
   @profile_name = '<<insert something here..>>',
   @recipients = '<<insert something here..>>',
   @body = @lBody,
   @subject = 'Key Accounts List ',
   @attach_query_result_as_file = 0,
   @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: Works flawlessly and exactly as intended. Thank you.